# Why javac "-source" flag doesn't work?

Tags: java, javac

I am testing the `javac -source` flag and I am a bit confuse about how it is supposed to work.

See this code as an example. It is a non-compatible Java5 code as the method `isEmpty()` is not defined for String in that version of the JDK.

```
public class TestJavac {
   public static void Main(String args[]) {
   String pippo = "pippo";   
   pippo.isEmpty();
   }
}
```

Trying to compile using:

```
javac -source 5 TestJavac.java
```

Then it works! 
This sounds weird to me, but maybe there is something that I am ignoring.
My `JAVA_HOME` point to a `1.6 JDK`.

Comment: Try compiling a source with generics and pass `-source 1.4` to see what the flag does.

Answer (score 5):

The source option is only for the language level, not for the API (supplied by the JDK runtime libraries).

There is a separate option (-bootclasspath -extdirs) to specify which JDK to use (and you need to get the appropriate jar files).

Note that there is also -target (which controls the output bytecode version).

You should always specify all (or even compile using the older JDK, which you more or less need anyway for that second switch to work)

Comment: If you have the older JDK, the safest option is likely to be to use that version of the JDK.

Comment: Yes. And in order to make the cross-compilation options like -bootclasspath work, you need the good parts of an older JDK anyway.

Comment: @Thilo  `-bootclasspath` Can be used with the classes of an earlier **JRE.**  It does not require a JDK of the target version.

Comment: I know. That is what I meant by "the good parts". What I wanted to say is that if you are going to download an older version of Java anyway, you might as well go the whole (and presumably safer) way and just get the old JDK and compile with that.

Answer (score 2):

The source flag is used only to verify language features, from the documentation of `-source` flag:

```
1.3  The compiler does not support assertions, generics, or other
     language features introduced after Java SE 1.3.

1.4  The compiler accepts code containing assertions, which were 
     introduced in Java SE 1.4.

1.5  The compiler accepts code containing generics and other language 
     features introduced in Java SE 5.

5    Synonym for 1.5.

1.6  No language changes were introduced in Java SE 6. However, encoding 
     errors in source files are now reported as errors instead of warnings 
     as in previous releases of Java SE.

6    Synonym for 1.6.

1.7  This is the default value. The compiler accepts code with features 
     introduced in Java SE 7.
```

as you can see, no changes were introduced in java 6.

Comment: You can use `@Override` for methods implementing an interface in Java 6 but not in Java 5.0.

Answer (score 1):

The `-source` only checks the java syntax, not the libraries included. e.g. it ignores the `@since 1.6` :(

Similarly `-target` will produce classes which will load on an older version of the JVM but might not run.

http://vanillajava.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/using-java-7-to-target-much-older-jvms.html