# Java version when using older target/source the api of the new java version is available

Tags: java, compiler-warnings

I have java 8 installed and compile my code to target and source 1.6.
That works but i don't want the code to compile if there is a java 8 specific function in the code. Everything compiles but if run on a machine running java 6 I get

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.Float.isFinite(F)

Is it possible to give this error at compile time?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/11794424/315306

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to also set the bootclasspath to a JDK 6 installation. Otherwise it will use JDK 8 and find all the new classes and methods you shouldn't be using.

Comment: ok thx, do you know how to do this in gradle script?

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -bootclasspath "PATH TO JDK 1.6"
```

You will need 1.6 also installed.